# raster2pgsql not in C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\bin

Tags: postgis, postgresql, raster2pgsql

After adding both

```
C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\bin
C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\lib
```

to my windows environmental variables PATH thing, I can't access raster2pgsql:

```
'raster2pgsql' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

I had a look in `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\bin`, but I can't actually find `raster2pgsql` there? Isn't this strange? I would expect it there?

I have postgresql (12.0) and postgis (3.0.0) installed

Comment: I don't know why, but postgresql12 and postgis3.0.0 don't come with raster2pgsql...
Wiped them from disk, reinstalled with postgresql10 + postgis2.5.1 ==> working

Comment: i've noticed this as well. it might have something to do with postgis_raster being a separate extension in postgis 3.0

Comment: https://info.crunchydata.com/blog/waiting-for-postgis-3-separate-raster-extension. Raster2pgsql should come with the bundle https://postgis.net/windows_downloads/. How did you make your installation?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone facing this issue, you can try to install `PostGIS` again. In windows, you can install it using the `Application Stack Builder` application. This will install the `raster2pgsql` and you can add this to environment variable and use it.